# A mysterious story that will leave you in the dark (1)

Tags: word, wordplay, story

This is the story of a man:

> He was designing a booster rocket that could put people on the moon. (3)
>   Every day he would drink a whole pot of hot coffee. (2)
>   One day he knocked his best mug off the table. (3)
>   It already had a chip on the rim from before. (2)
>   But that turned into a big crack because of the drop. (3)
>
> He looked for another cup but all he had was a glass that wasn't clean. (2)
>   It had a foul grape odor, like a cheap wine gone bad. (3)
>   The next day he got up at 10 o'clock. (2)
>   He opened his wallet and saw that he was down to his last buck. (3)
>   So he went to the bank to get some money. (2)
>
> But when he went in, he saw a dead body on the ground. (2)
>   There was a robber with a gun to the teller's head. (2)
>   A guard tried to jump the robber, and things quickly went to hell. (2)
>   Lead went flying everywhere, and the man took a bullet in the arm. (2)
>
> When it was over, his clothes were covered in blood. (2)
>   His arm was in a sling and his ear wouldn't stop ringing. (2)
>   At the police station, the getaway driver cut a deal and sang like a bird. (2)
>   It reduced his potentially long sentence to a slap on the wrist. (3)

Actually this story isn't really about anything.
Its entire purpose is to hide clues that point to a single word.
The numbers in parentheses are the number of clues in each line.

What is the word?

Hint:

> There is no trick to the puzzle, just trust your gut instinct, and you might be the first to find the answer. (3)

Hint 2:

> About 25% of the clues are related to [sports](/questions/tagged/sports).

Comment: Rot13(Hr fqzllzq, h.d mntmr, udqar, zcuzdqar, dsb, hlonqszms gdqd?)

Comment: @Jens rot13(Tenzzne ab, ohg jbeqf (abhaf, nqwrpgvirf, rgp) lrf.)

Comment: @Jens, think that's Rot1?

Comment: @Mohirl - There's no such thing as a rot1. I think you mean a Caesar Cipher with a shift of 1.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath The rot13.com website lets you rotate by amounts other than 13, and the dropdown selector you use to do it says ROT1 ... ROT25.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - That's fine, but ROT1 is not a real cipher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word we're looking for is

> SHOT.

The general idea is that

> each line contains some words that combine with "shot" to make new words or stock phrases.

Line by line:

> He was designing a **booster** rocket that could **put** people on the **moon**. (3)
>  Every day he would drink a whole **pot** of **hot** coffee. (2)
>  One day he knocked his **best** **mug** **off** the table. (3)
>  It already had a **chip** on the **rim** from before. (2)
>  But that turned into a **big** **crack** because of the **drop**. (3)

> He looked for another cup but all he had was a **glass** that wasn't **clean**. (2)
>  It had a **foul** **grape** odor, like a **cheap** wine gone bad. (3)
>  The next day he got **up** **at** 10 o'clock. (2)
>  He opened his wallet and saw that he was **down** to his **last** **buck**. (3)
>  So he went to the **bank** to get some **money**. (2)

> But when he went in, he saw a **dead** **body** on the ground. (2)
>  There was a robber with a **gun** to the teller's **head**. (2)
>  A guard tried to **jump** the robber, and things quickly went **to-hell**. (2)
>  Lead went **flying** everywhere, and the man took a bullet **in-the-arm**. (2)

> When it was **over**, his clothes were covered in **blood**. (2)
>  His arm was in a **sling** and his **ear** wouldn't stop ringing. (2)
>  At the police station, the getaway **driver** cut a deal and sang like a **bird**. (2) [not sure about "driver shot" -- golf?]
>  It reduced his potentially **long** sentence to a **slap** on the **wrist**. (3)

Title:

> "Shot in the dark".

Hint 1:

> "Trick shot" is obvious. Maybe "gut shot" and/or "first shot", though neither feels 100% convincing to me.

Comment: Very good!  For the iffy ones: Rot13(V vagraqrq sbe "bar fubg" (yvxr bar punapr) ba yvar 3 naq "fubg pybpx" (onfxrgonyy) ba yvar 8, ohg lbhe "fubg ng" vf npghnyyl n tbbq bar.  Yvar 17 jnf fhccbfrq gb or "phg fubg" (n tbys guvat).  Gur uvag jnf "thg fubg" (cbxre) naq "svefg fubg" (yvxr svefg punapr).)

Comment: Sounds reasonable :-).

Comment: @JS1 Well, I really went down the wrong lines with my thinking... rot13(Univat fcbggrq 'xnohy' fcyvg orgjrra jbeqf va cnen 3 naq 'tnaquv' gur fnzr va cnen 4, lbh qba'g jnag gb xabj ubj zhpu gvzr V fcrag frnepuvat sbe bgure guvatf yvaxrq gb Nfvn...) Well done Gareth :)